# How to request the formation of a wiki?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, closed-questions, editing

Was about to add an answer to my question from yesterday, with a bunch of bullet points given on various IRC channels I was perusing in the last 24 hours.

[Wiki of arguments for open-source business?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/8294)

But it's been closed. So I could edit asking for internal rather than external links. I could also ask for top 10 reasons, so it wouldn't be an infinite list.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

Such kind of open ended questions are simply not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model, no matter how they are phrased. Your question was closed because it asked for some resource, true, but your proposed question would also be closed because it is *too broad*.

[Real questions have *answers*, not *items* or *ideas* or *opinions*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). A question that asks for arguments or reasons for something is not a question in the Stack Exchange sense: any opinion is equally “valid”, but those opinions do not make an authoritative answer.

Your initial instinct to look for a *wiki* was very good: that's a much better medium to capture a resource like a list of arguments, compared to the Q&A model we have here. Other sites also have different expectations for questions. E.g. Reddit is good for discussions, and Quora is good for open-ended, writing-prompt style questions.